# JointDef Modify at Runtime

Tags: box2d, andengine

In my game, I want run time modification in object body so I want to modify the joint def according to situation. So provide comment for how to modify jointdef run time.

Comment: This is so very vague. You don't tell us what you've tried and it's hard to tell what you even want.

Comment: @JohnEye, Why up vote this question? Do you know the reason to upvote? Mouse over the up vote button *"This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear"* I don't see any of those attributes in this question.

Comment: I upvoted because I didn't like your comment and downvote so I wanted to restore some balance of the Force. The question may not show research effort, but it certainly is clear what Siddharth wants to accomplish. Also, he is new here so cut him some slack. Getting brutally downvoted without an answer can only discourage him from contributing in the future.

Comment: @JohnEye Siddharth has been part of GDSE for a few months now, he's been told about questions like this in the past. There's nothing "brutal" about the down vote. You're welcome to view [Siddharth's profile](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/14941/siddharth?tab=questions&sort=votes), you can see that he's asked 15 questions, only one of which is not at 0 or negative votes. His down votes far outweigh his up votes. The exact purpose of the down vote is to discourage this kind of contribution.

Comment: I see. Still, I think the question is valid and does not deserve so many downvotes.

Comment: @JohnEye A quote from your own answer says why it deserves downvotes: _"What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Specifying the problem better will help us provide you with a better answer."_ The reason for a downvote is: _"This question does not show any research effort; it is **unclear** or not useful"_. Not saying what he's trying to accomplish or specifying his actual problem means the question is unclear, and that's my reason for downvoting. If Siddharth was new or showed promise I would not downvote it past -1 or -2 to give him a chance, but he has had 15 questions now to get the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to do that unless you plan to reuse it. JointDef doesn't really do anything, as the name suggests, it is only a definition and even though you can change the fields, the Joint that was created using the JointDef will not change, as you probably discovered.

What you want to do is store a reference to the Joint that is created using the JointDef and then manipulate the Joint itself.

What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Specifying the problem better will help us provide you with a better answer.